# Weird shape button Customtkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, customtkinter

I am trying to create button using customtkinter in Python but the shape of the buttons are very weird. I found no solution browsing the internet.[image: Button shape bug]
Does anyone have a solution to this or encountered a similar issue ?

I tried several version of customtkinter and also removing anaconda from my device in case it could be comehow related to dependencies conflict

Comment: Try it without using anaconda and use python3.10 or python3.11. Which Linux version are you using?